# How to call an Action from a different class in Java

Tags: java, swing, action, jtabbedpane, actionevent

How would I call an Action from another class in Java? I got a CloseTabButton class online that allows a simple close tab button on each JTabbedPane, but when the tab is closed, I would like a dialog to pop up based on information (if file is not saved, ask to save it, etc.). This is the file:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class CloseTabButton extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JTabbedPane pane;
    public CloseTabButton(JTabbedPane pane, int index) {
        this.pane = pane;
        setOpaque(false);

        // CloseIcon class just had a button with an x painted on it
        Icon closeIcon = new CloseIcon();
        JButton close = new JButton(closeIcon);

        close.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(closeIcon.getIconWidth(), closeIcon.getIconHeight()));
        close.addActionListener(this);

        add(new JLabel(pane.getTitleAt(index), pane.getIconAt(index), JLabel.LEFT));
        add(close);

        pane.setTabComponentAt(index, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int i = pane.indexOfTabComponent(this);

        String fileName = pane.getToolTipTextAt(i);

        // Where I want to ask if user wants to save, etc.
        if (fileName == "Untitled") {
            // Do stuff
        }

        pane.remove(i); // Removes the tab

        // If tab count < 1, then disable the save and save as buttons on menu
        if (pane.getTabCount() < 1) {
            JFrame frame = (JFrame) pane.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent(); // Yes, there is that many in my code to get the parent JFrame

            int menuCount = frame.getJMenuBar().getMenuCount();

            for (int a = 0; a < menuCount; a++) {
                int itemCount = frame.getJMenuBar().getMenu(a).getItemCount();

                for (int b = 0; b < itemCount; b++) {
                    Component component = frame.getJMenuBar().getMenu(a).getMenuComponent(b);

                    if (!(component instanceof JSeparator)) {
                        // Not a seperator
                        String itemName = frame.getJMenuBar().getMenu(a).getItem(b).getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleName();
                        if (itemName == "Save As..") {
                            frame.getJMenuBar().getMenu(a).getItem(b).setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my main class I have actions listed like this:

```
static Action Close = new AbstractAction("Close") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        closeCurrentWindow(); // function that will close tab
    }
}
```

The other menu items are Actions as well, and as you can see, what I'm currently doing in the CloseTabButton class is quite frustrating, and most likely the wrong way to code it. Is there a much simpler way to do what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I might do is provide `ActionListener` support to the `CloseTabButton`, for example...

```
public class CloseTabButton extends JPanel {

    private JTabbedPane pane;

    public CloseTabButton(JTabbedPane pane, int index) {
        this.pane = pane;
        setOpaque(false);

        // CloseIcon class just had a button with an x painted on it
        Icon closeIcon = new CloseIcon();
        JButton close = new JButton(closeIcon);

        close.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(closeIcon.getIconWidth(), closeIcon.getIconHeight()));
        close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fireActionPerformed();
            }

        });

        add(new JLabel(pane.getTitleAt(index), pane.getIconAt(index), JLabel.LEFT));
        add(close);

        pane.setTabComponentAt(index, this);
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    protected void fireActionPerformed() {
        ActionListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
        ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "You could provide you own action command for each tab here");
        for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.actionPerformed(evt);
        }
    }

}
```

Basically, this now allows you to register your own `ActionListener`s to the `CloseTabButton`

Next, this, `fileName == "Untitled"`, is not how you compare `String`s in Java, you should be using something more like `"Untitled".equals(fileName)`

If you're menus are based on actual `Action`s, then you can simply disable the `Action`s themselves.  This would require a little bit of work, but a lot less of "guess" work then you're doing now.

Basically, you would monitor the `JTabbedPane` itself, monitoring for changes to the selected tab and updating the states of the individual `Action`s themselves

There a number of ways you could do this, like passing a reference of the `JTabbedPane` to the `Action`s so they can perform there own monitoring (but I'd use some kind of management interface which could more easily provide information to the `Action`s and decouple the code and the reliance on `JTabbedPane` directly, then you could be free to use `JInternalFrame`s instead).

You could have a "menu manager" which did a similar job, monitoring changes to the document container and changing the state of the menu `Action`s based on the current state, as an example

**Updated**

If you're making use of the `Action` API (which I would recommend), then you could simply do something like...

```
public class CloseTabButton extends JPanel {

    private JTabbedPane pane;

    public CloseTabButton(JTabbedPane pane, Action action, int index) {
        this.pane = pane;
        setOpaque(false);

        // CloseIcon class just had a button with an x painted on it
        Icon closeIcon = new CloseIcon();
        JButton close = new JButton(action);
        close.setIcon(closeIcon);
        close.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(closeIcon.getIconWidth(), closeIcon.getIconHeight()));

        add(new JLabel(pane.getTitleAt(index), pane.getIconAt(index), JLabel.LEFT));
        add(close);

        pane.setTabComponentAt(index, this);
    }

}
```

Passing in the `Action` for the close operation, then use the same action for both the `JMenuItem` and `JTabbedPane`.

The "core" issue would be how you would identify the "current" tab and document in a uniform manner

Comment: Even if theres a way to "trigger" the menu command as if the menuItem was clicked. I'm trying not to change my code too much haha.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: I can get access to the JMenuBar. But then there could possibly be a way to trigger a menu click event, such  as... frame.getJMenuBar.getMenu(a).getItem(b).click();  (I know in Java that's not correct, but in Javascript it can be done xD)

Comment: `doClick` is what you're after, having said that though, I advise against, hang on a sec

Comment: Why would you go against doClick()?

Comment: @vince, because, frankly, using a shared Action is simpler

Comment: Ah, okay. But nothing wrong with using it though, right? I mean, once I get my project done and I start cleaning up my code, I'll probably used shared Actions, but just to get it working for now, it should be fine, right?

Comment: So long as you have the `ActionListener`s set up properly.  The way you're digging around the menu's is really a good idea either, it assumes way to much about the state of the application